# JNI call to FindClass returns null when run on a new thread

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing an Android appliction and am using JNI to call Java functions from C++. The following code works as expected, retrieving a reference to a static Java method and then calling it.

```cpp
_JNIEnv *env = g_globalJniEnv;
jclass clazz = env->FindClass( "com/company/ClassName" );
jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID( clazz, "methodName", "()V" );
env->CallStaticVoidMethod( clazz, method );
```

However when I try to do the same thing on a `std::thread` the call to `FindClass` is returning NULL.

```cpp
std::thread callMethod( [] {
    JNIEnv *env;
    g_jvm->AttachCurrentThread( &env, NULL );
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass( "com/company/ClassName" );
    jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID( clazz, "methodName", "()V" );
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod( clazz, method );
    g_jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
} );
callMethod.detach();
```

Is there something missing from my implementation?

Comment: This is a common gotcha: only the main thread has the correct class loader set up.

Comment: What Java exception is thrown?